# UK Work Visa requirements for US citizen working for EU branch of US company

Tags: uk-visa, us-citizens, working

Recently I have transferred to an EU branch (Netherlands) of a US based company.  I am a US citizen with a US passport.

As part of the transfer I was sponsored and approved for residency/work permit as a "highly skilled immigrant" which gives me a Netherlands residency card.

Our office has recently be contracted by an UK based company to perform IT Engineering work that requires physically visiting their UK sites.  Time spent onsite would be 1-2 Months multiple times in a year.  What type of Visa application should I be pursuing?

- I am not being employed by a UK company.
- I am not living long term in the UK. (I would stay in a hotel).
- My company is not a UK company and cannot sponsor Visas for the UK

From my research the closest visa type that applies is that of a Tier 2 General Work Visa (from the occupation shortage list 2129 Engineering professionals not elsewhere classified).  I do not believe this is fully correct as I do not meet the first requirement of this visa:

- you’ve been offered a skilled job in the UK

Comment: Is the type of activity you’d be doing included in App3 Permitted Activities for Visitors? https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules How many visits / much time in total would you expect to spend in the UK? 1-2 months multiple times sounds like it might add up to ‘living in the UK through frequent or successive visits’

Comment: @Traveller, should only be 2 visits in a year each being 4-6 weeks or  2-4 months through out a full year.  To my reading of the document the work may fall under "Manufacturing and supply of goods to the UK" as we are supplying engineering services but I am not sure if we would qualify.